# How To Decrypt PGP Encrypted File (Encrypted by two PGP keys. Key1 having public, private key. Key2 having only in public key) Through JAVA API

Tags: java, pgp, openpgp

I have two PGP keys in PGP desktop.

- Key1 - Created in my PGP desktop. which contains both public and private key
- Key2 - Created by my client and shared with us only public key. I added key2 public key only in my PGP desktop.

Now I encrypted the file using above two keys. I can successfully decrypt the file by using PGP Desktop.

But I can not decrypt the file using Java API.

```
public static void decryptFile(File input, File key, char[] passwd, File destDir) throws Exception {
        File destFile = null;
        InputStream keyIn = new FileInputStream(key);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(input);
        InputStream in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(is);
        try {

            PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
            PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

            Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
            if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
            } else {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
            }

            Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> encDataObjects = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
            PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData encryptedData = null;
            List<Long> keyIds = new LinkedList<Long>();
            while (encDataObjects.hasNext()) {
                encryptedData = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) encDataObjects.next();
                long decipheringKeyID = encryptedData.getKeyID();
                System.out.println("****** Key ID ****** "+decipheringKeyID);
                keyIds.add(decipheringKeyID);
            }
            PGPSecretKey decipheringKey = readSecretKey(keyIn, keyIds);
            if (decipheringKey == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");
            }
            PGPPrivateKey decryptionKey = findPrivateKey(decipheringKey, passwd);
            if (decryptionKey == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Private key for message not found.");
            }

            PublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory dataDecryptorFactory = new BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory(decryptionKey);
            InputStream clear = encryptedData.getDataStream(dataDecryptorFactory);

            PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

            Object message = plainFact.nextObject();

            if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
                PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
                PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());
                message = pgpFact.nextObject();
            }
            if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
                // TODO: Verify file
                message = plainFact.nextObject();
            }
            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
                PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;

                InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                if(ld.getFileName().toString() == null || ld.getFileName().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    String[] fname = input.getAbsolutePath().split("\\\\");
                    destFile = new File(destDir,fname[fname.length-1].replace(".pgp", ""));
                }
                else
                {
                     destFile = new File(destDir, ld.getFileName());
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) {
                    out.write(ch);
                }
                byte[] returnBytes = out.toByteArray();
                out.close();
                fos.write(returnBytes);
                fos.close();
            } else {
                throw new PGPException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (keyIn != null) {
                keyIn.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: exception encrypting session info: unknown block type
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory.recoverSessionData(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.pgp.util.PGPUtils.decryptFile(PGPUtils.java:312)
    at com.pgp.util.PGPUtils.main(PGPUtils.java:576)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: unknown block type
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.decodeBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.processBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: exception encrypting session info: unknown block type
    at com.pgp.util.PGPUtils.decryptFile(PGPUtils.java:373)
    at com.pgp.util.PGPUtils.main(PGPUtils.java:576)
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What's the output of `pgpdump` or `gpg --list-packets` on the encrypted message? This might be an issue with unsupported algorithms, or you're somehow messing up with the file when loading it.

Comment: is there any algorithms(Java API) to decrypt the encrypted file. The file is encrypted by using 2 PGP keys as i said above.

Comment: The information I requested is very important for answering your question; additionally you should mention what Java implementation you're using and which version.